# How Can This Unnamed Function Be Called?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I was reviewing the script provided by Facebook in order to run it's authorization. I ran into this puzzling bit of code:

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

As an unnamed function in its own scope, it would seem like this could never be called, but there it is, included in the boilerplate script.

What is going on here?

Comment: It is already called.

Comment: It's an IIFE. It calls itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is an [**Immediatly Invoked Function Expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

If you notice the function has 3 arguments `d`, `s`, `id` then you will notice the function body.. At the end it calls it self passing in the args `document`, `script`, `facebook-jssdk`.

All this function does is creates a script such as.

`<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>`

and inserts it before the first script tag in the document.